# How can I add background colour to node text and total count in d3 sankey

Tags: d3.js, sankey-diagram

How can I give red color to node text and green color to node total count? I tried a lot but did not get any success. Since I am new to d3 any help will be appreciated.

I have tried one solution but it didn't work for me [d3 sankey](http://jsfiddle.net/saneep/bqpy6f4c/)

```
d3.sankey = function () {
    var sankey = {},
    nodeWidth = 24,
        nodePadding = 8,
        size = [1, 1],
        nodes = [],
        links = [];

    sankey.nodeWidth = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return nodeWidth;
        nodeWidth = +_;
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.nodePadding = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return nodePadding;
        nodePadding = +_;
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.nodes = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return nodes;
        nodes = _;
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.links = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return links;
        links = _;
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.size = function (_) {
        if (!arguments.length) return size;
        size = _;
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.layout = function (iterations) {
        computeNodeLinks();
        computeNodeValues();
        computeNodeBreadths();
        computeNodeDepths(iterations);
        computeLinkDepths();
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.relayout = function () {
        computeLinkDepths();
        return sankey;
    };

    sankey.link = function () {
        var curvature = .5;

        function link(d) {
            var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
                x1 = d.target.x,
                xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
                x2 = xi(curvature),
                x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
                y0 = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2,
                y1 = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
            return "M" + x0 + "," + y0 + "C" + x2 + "," + y0 + " " + x3 + "," + y1 + " " + x1 + "," + y1;
        }

        link.curvature = function (_) {
            if (!arguments.length) return curvature;
            curvature = +_;
            return link;
        };

        return link;
    };

    // Populate the sourceLinks and targetLinks for each node.
    // Also, if the source and target are not objects, assume they are indices.
    function computeNodeLinks() {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            node.sourceLinks = [];
            node.targetLinks = [];
        });
        links.forEach(function (link) {
            var source = link.source,
                target = link.target;
            if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
            if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
            source.sourceLinks.push(link);
            target.targetLinks.push(link);
        });
    }

    // Compute the value (size) of each node by summing the associated links.
    function computeNodeValues() {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            node.value = Math.max(
            d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value),
            d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value));
        });
    }

    // Iteratively assign the breadth (x-position) for each node.
    // Nodes are assigned the maximum breadth of incoming neighbors plus one;
    // nodes with no incoming links are assigned breadth zero, while
    // nodes with no outgoing links are assigned the maximum breadth.
    function computeNodeBreadths() {
        var remainingNodes = nodes,
            nextNodes,
            x = 0;

        while (remainingNodes.length) {
            nextNodes = [];
            remainingNodes.forEach(function (node) {
                node.x = x;
                node.dx = nodeWidth;
                node.sourceLinks.forEach(function (link) {
                    nextNodes.push(link.target);
                });
            });
            remainingNodes = nextNodes;
            ++x;
        }

        //
        moveSinksRight(x);
        scaleNodeBreadths((width - nodeWidth) / (x - 1));
    }

    function moveSourcesRight() {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            if (!node.targetLinks.length) {
                node.x = d3.min(node.sourceLinks, function (d) {
                    return d.target.x;
                }) - 1;
            }
        });
    }

    function moveSinksRight(x) {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            if (!node.sourceLinks.length) {
                node.x = x - 1;
            }
        });
    }

    function scaleNodeBreadths(kx) {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            node.x *= kx;
        });
    }

    function computeNodeDepths(iterations) {
        var nodesByBreadth = d3.nest()
            .key(function (d) {
            return d.x;
        })
            .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
            .entries(nodes)
            .map(function (d) {
            return d.values;
        });

        //
        initializeNodeDepth();
        resolveCollisions();
        for (var alpha = 1; iterations > 0; --iterations) {
            relaxRightToLeft(alpha *= .99);
            resolveCollisions();
            relaxLeftToRight(alpha);
            resolveCollisions();
        }

        function initializeNodeDepth() {
            var ky = d3.min(nodesByBreadth, function (nodes) {
                return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * nodePadding) / d3.sum(nodes, value);
            });

            nodesByBreadth.forEach(function (nodes) {
                nodes.forEach(function (node, i) {
                    node.y = i;
                    node.dy = node.value * ky;
                });
            });

            links.forEach(function (link) {
                link.dy = link.value * ky;
            });
        }

        function relaxLeftToRight(alpha) {
            nodesByBreadth.forEach(function (nodes, breadth) {
                nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                    if (node.targetLinks.length) {
                        var y = d3.sum(node.targetLinks, weightedSource) / d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value);
                        node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
                    }
                });
            });

            function weightedSource(link) {
                return center(link.source) * link.value;
            }
        }

        function relaxRightToLeft(alpha) {
            nodesByBreadth.slice().reverse().forEach(function (nodes) {
                nodes.forEach(function (node) {
                    if (node.sourceLinks.length) {
                        var y = d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, weightedTarget) / d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value);
                        node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
                    }
                });
            });

            function weightedTarget(link) {
                return center(link.target) * link.value;
            }
        }

        function resolveCollisions() {
            nodesByBreadth.forEach(function (nodes) {
                var node,
                dy,
                y0 = 0,
                    n = nodes.length,
                    i;

                // Push any overlapping nodes down.
                nodes.sort(ascendingDepth);
                for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    node = nodes[i];
                    dy = y0 - node.y;
                    if (dy > 0) node.y += dy;
                    y0 = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding;
                }

                // If the bottommost node goes outside the bounds, push it back up.
                dy = y0 - nodePadding - size[1];
                if (dy > 0) {
                    y0 = node.y -= dy;

                    // Push any overlapping nodes back up.
                    for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
                        node = nodes[i];
                        dy = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding - y0;
                        if (dy > 0) node.y -= dy;
                        y0 = node.y;
                    }
                }
            });
        }

        function ascendingDepth(a, b) {
            return a.y - b.y;
        }
    }

    function computeLinkDepths() {
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            node.sourceLinks.sort(ascendingTargetDepth);
            node.targetLinks.sort(ascendingSourceDepth);
        });
        nodes.forEach(function (node) {
            var sy = 0,
                ty = 0;
            node.sourceLinks.forEach(function (link) {
                link.sy = sy;
                sy += link.dy;
            });
            node.targetLinks.forEach(function (link) {
                link.ty = ty;
                ty += link.dy;
            });
        });

        function ascendingSourceDepth(a, b) {
            return a.source.y - b.source.y;
        }

        function ascendingTargetDepth(a, b) {
            return a.target.y - b.target.y;
        }
    }

    function center(node) {
        return node.y + node.dy / 2;
    }

    function value(link) {
        return link.value;
    }

    return sankey;
};


/* ------------------- our code ------------------------ */

var units = "Widgets";

var margin = {
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    bottom: 10,
    left: 10
},
width = 700 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"), // zero decimal places
    format = function (d) {
        return formatNumber(d) + " " + units;
    },
    color = d3.scale.category20();

// append the svg canvas to the page
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// Set the sankey diagram properties
var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(36)
    .nodePadding(40)
    .size([width, height]);

var path = sankey.link();


var data = [{
    "source": "A",
        "target": "X",
        "value": 5
}, {
    "source": "A",
        "target": "Y",
        "value": 7
}, {
    "source": "A",
        "target": "Z",
        "value": 6
}, {
    "source": "B",
        "target": "X",
        "value": 2
}, {
    "source": "B",
        "target": "Y",
        "value": 9
}, {
    "source": "B",
        "target": "Z",
        "value": 4
}];


//set up graph in same style as original example but empty
graph = {
    "nodes": [],
        "links": []
};

data.forEach(function (d) {
    graph.nodes.push({
        "name": d.source
    });
    graph.nodes.push({
        "name": d.target
    });
    graph.links.push({
        "source": d.source,
            "target": d.target,
            "value": +d.value
    });
});

// return only the distinct / unique nodes
graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
    .key(function (d) {
    return d.name;
})
    .map(graph.nodes));

// loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
    graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
    graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
});

//now loop through each nodes to make nodes an array of objects
// rather than an array of strings
graph.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
    graph.nodes[i] = {
        "name": d
    };
});

sankey.nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .layout(32);

// add in the links
var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
    .append("path")
    .attr("class", "link")
    .attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkLabel" + i; })
    .attr("d", path)
    .style("stroke-width", function (d) {
       return Math.max(1, d.dy);
    })
    .sort(function (a, b) {
       return b.dy - a.dy;
    })



// add in the nodes
var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
    .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "node")
    .attr("transform", function (d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")";
})
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
    .origin(function (d) {
    return d;
})
    .on("dragstart", function () {
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this);
})
    .on("drag", dragmove));

// add the rectangles for the nodes
node.append("rect")
    .attr("height", function (d) {
    return d.dy;
})
    .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
    .style("fill", function (d) {
    return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, ""));
})
    .style("stroke", function (d) {
    return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2);
})
    .append("title")
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value);
});

// add in the title for the nodes
node.append("text")
    .attr("x", -26)
    .attr("y", function (d) {
    return d.dy / 2;
})
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .attr("text-anchor", "end")
    .attr("transform", null)
    .text(function (d) {
    return d.name + " (" + d.value + ")";
})
    .filter(function (d) {
    return d.x < width / 2;
})
    .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
    .attr("text-anchor", "start");

/* add labels to graphs */
var labelText = svg.selectAll(".labelText")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("class","labelText")
    .attr("dx",130)
    .attr("dy",0)
  .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkLabel" + i;})
    .text(function(d,i) {                                 
        return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + " : " + d.value;});

// the function for moving the nodes
function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform",
        "translate(" + d.x + "," + (
    d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/saneep/bqpy6f4c/